# How to list joined entity property instead of full entity in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have two tables in an SQL Database named Computer and Department in which they have a 1-To-Many relationship through a table named DepartamentComputer (PK is ComputerId).

I am trying to list all computers with their respective Department Name on a DataGridView but when it comes to the Department on the DataGridView it actually shows the entity instead of the Name of the Department like this: [DataGridView row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMKll.png)

These are the methods required to get all computers from a generic repository:

```
    public Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();  
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Computadora>> ListarAsync()
    {
        return await _unitOfWork.Computadora.GetAllAsync();
    }
```

And these are the methods to populate the DataGridView

```
    private async void ListarComputadoras()
    {
        var lista = await ListarAsync();
        Popular(lista);
    }

    public void Popular(IEnumerable<Computadora> computadoras)
    {
        var bs = new BindingSource() {DataSource = computadoras.ToList()};
        dgvDatos.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

How can I select the property Name of table Department and show it on the DataGridView instead of showing the Name of the Entity?

Thank you!

Edit: I forgot to mention. I want to avoid the use of anonymous types because I have more logic that depends on the list of computers and with anonymous types that logic would break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void Popular(IEnumerable<Computadora> computadoras)
{
  var data = (from c in computadoras 
                select new {
                          CodigoInterno = c.CodigoInterno,
                          Departamento = c.Departamento.Name, // If the department entity has a name property.
                         // assign the properties to be shown in grid like this
                          }).ToList();

    var bs = new BindingSource() {DataSource = data};
    dgvDatos.DataSource = bs;
}
```

If you don't like to use an anonymous type, create a class with the required properties and use it as follows.

```
public void Popular(IEnumerable<Computadora> computadoras)
{
          var data = (from c in computadoras 
                    select new Computer{
                                      CodigoInterno = c.CodigoInterno,
                                      Departamento = c.Departamento.Name, //If the department entity has a name property.
                                     // assign the properties to be shown in grid like this
                                 }).ToList();

            var bs = new BindingSource() {DataSource = data};
            dgvDatos.DataSource = bs;
}

public class Computer
{
    public string CodigoInterno {get;set;}
    public string Departamento {get;set;}
    //add properties here
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works but is it possible to do it avoiding the use of anonymous types? Because I have more logic that depends on the Computer list and with anonymous types that logic would break.

Comment: If you don't like to use an anonymous type, create a class for that and use it. Check out the updated answer